# No module named 'whois' Despite Already Installing 'python-whois'

Tags: python, python-module, whois

## Context

---

I am making a project using Python and have a virtual environment installed called `venv`. Here is the information for the virtual environment:

Version and Modules Installed:

[image]

I am on a linux machine that has a package installed called `whois` via `apt`.

I am using VSC and its built-in terminal.

Here is the code that I run using the terminal with the virtual environment activated.

[image]

## The Problem

---

The following error occurs when the code tries to import the module.

```
┌──(venv)─(narwhal㉿WhoAreWe)-[~/Documents/Projects/PassCon]
└─$ python ./WHOIS/custom_whois.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/narwhal/Documents/Projects/PassCon/./WHOIS/custom_whois.py", line 1, in <module>
    import whois
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'whois'
```

## What Have I Tried

---

I have tried to not use the virtual environment and run it normally and it does work but from what I understand it is using the `whois` package installed via `apt` (I found out that it doesn't work as I am using `whois()` instead of `query()` which is used by the APT-installed `whois`).

I also have uninstalled and re-installed `python-whois` multiple times.

### FYI

I do not wish to uninstall the `apt` version of whois as I need it for my day to day. I doubt that its the problem, but I hope its not the only solution to fix my problem.

I also want to use `python-whois` so it is easily installed for users.

Comment: Try running `python -m site` in your venv to see where Python is searching for modules. Then, check whether or not `whois` actually exists in any of those locations.

Comment: if pip reports the package is installed but python can't, there's a big chance that pip is not using the *same* python. Once you have activated venv, do `python -mpip freeze`  in that venv, does the package show up ?

Comment: You're a savior, Gabe. The issue was that for some reason, my `venv` did not have pip installed in the modules directory and wasn't actually installing anything. Do you want to post an actual answer, so I can close this? Or should I give the answer in your stead? Edit: Thanks Rasjani. That also helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Gabe and Rasjani for showing me how to check the directory in which my virtual environment was checking for installed modules, I have figured out the solution.

First, I used `python -m site` to check the directory listing and searched each one and noticed that PIP was not installed in any of them and none of them had the modules I "installed".

The simplest fix was to uninstall my current virtual environment and follow [this step-by-step](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/) on how to properly initiate a virtual environment, check if its successful, and install the modules.

Lesson learned: Don't blindly jump in and properly set up your environment.